# Find Id in String list

Tags: c#, list

I'm a novice when it comes to programing. I'm working on a sort of grocery shopping list. I have a string list, where the user can add groceries to:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Now if the user wants to remove a certain object(grocery) in the list i would like him to do it with numbers instead of typing in the grocery name in the console window, which i have accomplished here:

```
case 2:
Console.WriteLine("What would you like to remove from the list?");
int removeGroc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
list.RemoveAt(removeGroc);
break;
```

What I want to do is make sure to check that if the user enters for example number 5 but there are only 3 objects in the list, so the user will be asked to enter a number again since there are only 3 objects in the list(0, 1 and 2). I've searched everywhere and tried different things but they don't seem to work or my knowledge is to bad to understand it. So how would i go about doing this? I have a jist of what i need to do but I dont know how to do it. I'm thinking that i need to find the "id" of the list and then check if it exists, but I can't seem to find how to do this online.

Here is the edit which worked thanks to the comments if any other novice sees this:

```
Console.WriteLine("What would you like to remove from the list?");
var removeGroc = Console.ReadLine();
int removeGrocId;
bool parseSuccess = int.TryParse(removeGroc, out removeGrocId);
if (removeGrocId < list.Count)
   list.RemoveAt(removeGrocId);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Write a valid number!");
```

Comment: the id is what is called the index.

Comment: `if(removeGroc < list.Count) list.RemoveAt(removeGroc);`

Comment: You also need to handle the case where the user enters something else other than a number. Don't use `Convert.ToInt32` and use [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) instead.

Comment: Your code should look something like this: `int removeGroc; do { Console.WriteLine("Enter item id to remove"); } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out removeGroc) || removeGroc >= list.Count);`

Comment: Thansk for answering guys, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with

```
list.Count; //return the number of the items in the list
```

So you validate it with the number of the items in the list:

```
if(removeGroc > listCount){ //do someting }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found it really useful to use a helper method that will get a number from the user. This method uses [`TryParse`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPmpjvns3gAhXJHDQIHfLHDskQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.int32.tryparse&usg=AOvVaw35Ul21c7qYu7DttNERjnwp) to convert the input to a number, which is really handy because it returns a `bool` that indicates success, and then the converted number is set to an `out` parameter. Note that in your method above, if the user enters an invalid number, like "two", it will throw an exception.

The method below also takes in an optional string "prompt", which is displayed to the user, and then it loops until they enter a valid value:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}
```

Now, to get an integer from the user, we would just do:

```
int removeGroc = GetIntFromUser("What would you like to remove from the list?");
```

This can be improved slightly by adding a feature where instead of asking the question again in a new line (which can slowly eat up the console window space if they keep entering incorrect data), we can use the `Console.CursorTop` and `Console.SetCursorPosition` to overwrite the current line with blank spaces (clearing their original input) and then write the question again on the same line:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        // Set the cursor to the beginning of the line,
        // write a blank line, and set it to the beginning again
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));

    return result;
}
```

Alright, now we just need to add a way to specify valid entries, so that if they enter a number but it's not valid for our scenario, it will continue to ask them for valid input.

The first thing I did was write a bunch of overloads of this method that took in things like `minValue`, `maxValue`, even a `List<int> validNumbers` and `List<int> invalidNumbers`, and then had logic to check if the number they entered met all these criteria.

But since we have the ability to pass a **function** to a method, I opted instead to just let the client pass in *their own validation function* that takes in an `int` and returns a `bool`. This way the same method can be re-used for all kinds of scenarios:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
        Console.Write(prompt);

    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
             (validator != null && !validator.Invoke(result)));

    return result;
}
```

Now we have a method that will take any type of validation we want, and will apply it to the user input. For your example, the requirements are that the number is greater than or equal to `0`, and less than or equal to `list.Count - 1` (to get a valid index in the `list`).  This can be written as a lambda method like:

```
i => i >= 0 && i <= list.Count - 1
```

So, applying this to your example, we can now simply do something like:

```
case 2:
{
    int minVal = 0;
    int maxVal = list.Count - 1;
    int removeGroc = GetIntFromUser($"Enter the item to remove ({minVal} - {maxVal}): ",
        i => i >= minVal && i <= maxVal);
    list.RemoveAt(removeGroc);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `?.` operator which is one of my favorites right now.

Comment: By the way I really like your third example.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Thanks! In my own method I do have `!(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true)`, but I didn't want to explain that part here too. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this and also thanks for explaining it so well!!

Comment: @kastravec You're welcome, hope it helps. It comes in handy a lot.